# Trigger to monitor is value acceptable or not

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I have Oracle 11g and a table called CODES and there is column ID and CODESA as follow:

```
ID  CODESA
1   9999
1   8889
2   77777
2   99999
3   1234
3   4321
4   565656
etc.
```

Then I need to update another table CODES2 and column CODESB based on ID in CODES table

I need a trigger to monitor this.

Let´s say I monitoring ID = 2 with this trigger and all different CODESA´s under that ID,
you can see that only these are possible to update in CODESB

```
2   77777
2   99999
```

How to make a trigger to launch if user is trying to enter some code in CODESB
which is for example from ID = 3 ?

Appreciate your help. Thanks,

Some_user

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some example UPDATE / INSERT statements, and the expected result?

Comment: The normal answer is that we wouldn't use a trigger for that, we would build a foreign key on `CODES2(id, codesb)` referencing `CODES(id, codesa)`. So if you have considered that approach we would be interested to know your reasons for rejecting it.

Answer (score 0):

@APC is correct. We can use foreign key but lets say OP dont want those columns to be primary or unique, in that case trigger is the solution.

> ```
> Create or replace trigger codes2_trg
> Before insert or update On codes2
> For each row
> Declare 
> Cnt number;
> Begin
> Select count(1) into cnt
> From codes where (id, codesa) = (:new.id, :new.codesb);
>
> If cnt = 0 then
> Raise_application_error('-20001', 'these balues are not allowed.');
> End if;
>
> End;
> /
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Be aware that if you go with a trigger based solution, you need to cover a lot more use cases than you do with a foreign key.  You'd need a trigger on `codes` to prevent deletes or updates if there are rows in `codes2` that refer to them.  You'd need to deal with concurrency if someone is modifying a `codes` row at the same time that you're doing an insert.

Comment: @JustinCave, perfect!!